# A GFX card with two DVI and one HDMI with audio?

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, dvi, tv

I haven't upgraded my PC for a while nor kept up to date with pc hardware since 2007, but have recently come up with a requirement and I am wondering if I can solve it!

Are there any graphics cards out there that have two DVIs and one HDMI output, with the HDMI supporting sound over it? Basically, I've got a two PC monitor setup, and both monitors are connected to the two DVI's of my GTX9800+. I want to upgrade my card to say, GTX 460, but can't find if there is such with two DVIs (for my monitors) and one HDMI with audio (for my TV). So I am wondering, if such solution possible at all?

I noticed that there are some cards out there with two DVI's and one mini-HDMI, but they all say 'HDMI Output Yes x 1 (via DVI to HDMI adaptor x 1 )', which probably means that because of the DVI element, the audio won't work. Is this true? Such card is an exmaple:

http://uk.asus.com/Graphics_Cards/NVIDIA_Series/ENGTX460_DirectCU2DI1GD5/#specifications

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of cards out there which support that configuration.

The one I am using (now nearly 3 years old) is an AMD 5870, which has two monitors connected via DVI and one via HDMI.

However I am reasonably sure that is works for all ATI cards of that generation (58xx and 57xx) and for their successors. And where one brand (AMD) has it, the other large GPU builder is sure to follow.

Comment: Note that while GPU support is required for certain outputs, the actual available outputs depends on the *card* manufacturer. AMD makes the GPU, but not the card, and there can be many cards with differing supported outputs using the same GPU.

Comment: Correct. But there will be (lots of) cards out there. TomaszRykala might need to check before buying a specific card, but I am sure that there are cards out there which need his requirements.

Comment: OK, it's gonna be a contest between the GTX460 and 5850 when it comes to the purchase now now :-)